# Can I run a correlation test in order to find out if a percentage change between two similar questions is significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, survey

I ran an online-survey (173 participants) where I asked a question on participants' initial willingness to shop online. After asking other, but related questions with different scenarios (in random order), where participants had the opportunity to voluntarily chat with a fashion consultant, I asked the same question again (but now they had the opportunity to chat with a fashion consultant).

Now, I am looking for a statistical way to find determine if their response changes significantly. Would I need to run a correlation test?

Example:

- initial question: total 33 of the 173 participants said they would shop online
- for the people who answered the first question NOT with "online", I made a follow up question: total 20 of the remaining 140 participants said they would now shop online.
  The percentage change is ((20+33)/173) - (33/173) = 12%

Comment: So the question being asked is dichotomous?  That is, the only answers are yes or no?

Comment: Hi Sal, many thanks for your question. There were 4 options: 
(a) "Online"
(b) "Offline"
(c) "It depends"
(d) "I don't know". 
However I think for the significance test we could simplify it to 
"Online" (a) and
"NOT online" (b, c & d)

Comment: And you are able to match the answer for each question for each respondent?  That is, you know Person A answered "offline" before and "online" after ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I can match the answers for each respondent.

Comment: If the question is whether the responses changed before and after, then correlation wouldn't answer that question.  A perfect correlation would indicate that people answered the same before and after.  That's not really the question you are asking. ... I think the standard statistical test for dichotomous data looked at before and after is McNemar's test.  This looks at if more people changed from yes to no as changed from no to yes (and ignores those who didn't change).  An effect size could be Cohen's g or a type of odds ratio.

Comment: Can you say how many people change from No to Yes and whether anyone changed from Yes to No? If so, please edit this information into your Question.

Comment: Now I explained my question in more details and I added exact numbers. Hope you can follow. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Please add extra information in comments as an edit to the main post. Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: If I understand the new information in the question ---- that only the people who had selected "not online" to the first question received the second question to see if they had changed their minds --- makes the analysis more difficult. While 20 out of the 140 people changed their minds from "not online" to "online", you don't know if anyone changed their minds from "online" to "not online"

Comment: I thought about using something like a binomial test ---- or comparable Monte Carlo simulation, chi-square test, or confidence interval for a proportion ---- to compare the 20 out of 140 to theoretical proportion of 0.  But, as far as I can tell, none of these methods yield a reasonable result.

Comment: Many thanks Sal. My thought was that, if someone who was initially in favour of online-shopping, would not change his mind if there was the voluntary possibility to use an online chat. So i thought instead of deleting those respondents who changed from online to offline (because it makes no sense) I just leave them out for the second question. So if I understand you correctly, none of your proposed methods would yield to a statistical significant result? Thanks again :)

Comment: Based on the experimental design, my best advice is to calculate a confidence interval, appropriate for a dichotomous proportion.  I wouldn't make a statistical inference based on that confidence interval.